# Best way to map a Observable with another

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm working in a Angular project and I have an Observable `A`. `A` emits a value from HTTP request and I want to filter such value with another Observable depending on the user role: admin, superuser and user. I solved using `switchMap` and if/else, but I think there is better way. My solution is:

```
getObervableA.pipe(
    switchMap(itens => {
        function filterItens(allowedItens) {
            return itens.filter(item => {
                return allowedItens.some(({id}) => id === item.id);
            });
        }

        if (isAdmin) {
            return of(itens);
        } else if (isSuperuser) {
            getSuperuserAllowedItens.pipe(map(allowedItens => filterItens(allowedItens)));
        } else {
            getUserAllowedItens.pipe(map(allowedItens => filterItens(allowedItens)));
        }
    }),
).subscribe(
    // do something with A filtered
)
```

I'm suspecting that I can pipe the if/else inside `switchMap`...

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using a if/else it's better to compose your observables for these types of uses cases. 
It allows better readability and easier to test

If you don't need the switchMap we can do an easier way by using `filter` & `merge` So something like this:

```
 function filterItens(allowedItens, itens) {
      return itens.filter(item => {
        return allowedItens.some(({ id }) => id === item.id);
      });
    }

   admin$ = source.pipe(filter(() => isAdmin));
   superUser$ = source.pipe(filter(() => isSuperUser), mergeMap((itens) => getSuperuserAllowedItens.pipe(map(allowedItens => filterItens(allowedItens, itens))))
   user$ = source.pipe(filter(() => !isAdmin && !isSuperUser), mergeMap((itens) => getUserAllowedItens.pipe(map(allowedItens => filterItens(allowedItens, itens))))
   getObervableA.pipe(merge(admin$, superUser$, user$)).subscribe()
```

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways of doing it, depending on your situation. Your solution is already correct. However, if your `Observables` are independent on each other, `forkJoin` is very useful and could be more performant:

```
forkJoin(getObservableA, getSuperuserAllowedItens, getUserAllowedItens)
    .pipe(map(([itens, superuserItens, userItens]) => {

        if (isAdmin) {
            return itens;
        }

        if (isSuperUser) {
            return itens.filter(item => superuserItens.some(({id}) => id === item.id));
        }

        return itens.filter(item => userItens.some(({id}) => id === item.id));
    }))
```

Here is the one liner (almost) with ternary operator:

```
forkJoin(getObservableA, getSuperuserAllowedItens, getUserAllowedItens)
    .pipe(map(([itens, superuserItens, userItens]) => {
        return isAdmin ? itens :
            isSuperUser ? itens.filter(item => superuserItens.some(({id}) => id === item.id)) :
                itens.filter(item => userItens.some(({id}) => id === item.id))
    }))
```

Also, if your conditions are mutually exclusive, aka, an admin cannot be a super user, nor a super user can be a normal user (or rather, one person can only have one role), then the code boils down rather simple:

```
forkJoin(getObservableA, getSuperuserAllowedItens, getUserAllowedItens)
    .pipe(map(([itens, superuserItens, userItens]) => {
        return itens.filter(item => {
            return isAdmin || superuserItens.some(({id}) => id === item.id) || userItens.some(({id}) => id === item.id)
        })
    }))
```